# Rubocop doesn't see Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubocop, pre-commit

I have configured [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) gem into my project with git commit hook using [pre-commit](https://github.com/observing/pre-commit) and I have faced the problem: rubocop evaluating on commit hook checks Gemfile but when I manually run `rubocop` in project's directory it isn't check it. Actually when I run `rubocop Gemfile` it works but it's so inconvenient for me... Maybe someone has already solved this problem?

Comment: are you using a recent release of Rubocop locally and at remote?

Comment: tomorrow I will check. Is it important? Can't find any information about change behaviour of Gemfile checking in rubocop last versions @ashmaroli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Rubocop Changelog for **v0.48.0**:

> **Changes**
>
> **#3997:** Include all ruby files by default and exclude non-ruby files. *(@dorian)*